# Maven parent POM download

Tags: maven, pom.xml, parent

I'm new to Maven, so I'm wondering why Maven will actually download the parent.

Here is my sample directory:

```
├── hazriq-module
│   ├── document-generator
│   |       ├── src folder
│   |       └── pom.xml (document-generator)
│   └── pom.xml (hazriq-module) 
└── pom.xml (hazriq-parent)
```

My hazriq-parent .pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.hazriq</groupId>
  <artifactId>hazriq-parent</artifactId>
  <version>${hazriq.verion}</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
    <hazriq.verion>1.0.0</hazriq.verion>
  </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>hazriq-module</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

My hazriq-module .pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.hazriq</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazriq-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>hazriq-module</artifactId>
    <name>hazriq-module</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>${hazriq.verion}</version>

    <modules>
        <module>document-generator</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

My document-generator .pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.hazriq</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazriq-module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.hazriq.hazriq-module</groupId>
    <artifactId>document-generator</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>
```

When I try to run `mvn install`:

```
$ mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.hazriq:hazriq-module:${hazriq.verion} (C:\development\hzrqmvn\hazriq-module\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.hazriq:hazriq-parent:pom:1.0.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
 until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

My questions are:
1. Why will Maven actually go and try to download the `hazriq-parent`? from the `repo.maven.apache.org`? (Refer to the output of my `mvn clean install` above.
2. How can I successfully build my project?

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't it? If you build a module, all its parent modules have to be resolved recursively. Same goes for all dependencies.

This means those artefacts have to be either in the configured remote repository (Maven Central by default) or your local one. You can add it to your local repository by doing a `mvn install`.

Comment: This is a new repo, so I dont have any artefact on any of my remote repo yet. I did tried `mvn install` though but you can see that I got the error mentioned in my question above.

Comment: @HazriqIshak you have to do a `mvn install` on the parent first.

Comment: Yup. I did but it throws me an error. Its in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason my one is failing is because of the placeholder in the `<version>`.

I changed my parent .pom to:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.hazriq</groupId>
  <artifactId>hazriq-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>hazriq-module</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

My module .pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.hazriq</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazriq-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>hazriq-module</artifactId>
    <name>hazriq-module</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0</version>

    <modules>
        <module>document-generator</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

My document-generator .pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.hazriq</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazriq-module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.hazriq.hazriq-module</groupId>
    <artifactId>document-generator</artifactId>


</project>
```

A good read on this issue: https://jeanchristophegay.com/maven-unique-version-multi-modules-build-en/